# How to: using OpenXML to Update Fields in Word

Tags: openxml, docx

I am working on a prototype where I am assembling word documents using OpenXML from various different documents like other word docs.

My question is this: How do you update the fields in those word documents without having word installed.

Fields include numbered sections in each section of the assembled document, updating the table of content field and also formula fields, like =SUM(Above) that should do the work on data inserted into a table during runtime.

These documents will never be opened by end users as word documents since they must be converted to PDF on the server.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically update formula field after generating Open XML Word document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122406/automatically-update-formula-field-after-generating-open-xml-word-document)