# OpenXML: update Embedded excel in Word document

Tags: openxml

I am updating word template with data run time using OpenXML. My question is after entering cell values in embedded Excel, it is not reflecting when I open the word document after process.

e.g. I have one word template document which has total 6 embedded Excel object. Each embedded Excel has three worksheets (e.g. display, data & settings). Once I have data while running application, the code is filling the value in data worksheet. The Display worksheet shows the value from Data worksheet based on Formulas applied on cells on display worksheet. Once entire process completes I opened newly generated word document, it shows Excel Display worksheet without the values applied. If I will edit/open worksheet from Word document than it get refreshed and showing new values.

Is there way in OpenXML to fix this issue?

Comment: Dynamic content in Word is supported by "fields"; most must be updated explicitly. Embedded Excel workbooks are also wrapped in a field, although I've never tested whether forcing field updates actualize changed data... For a really good explanation and your options see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfedev/2010/08/08/openxml-how-to-refresh-a-field-when-the-document-is-opened/ and there's also already a StackOverflow posting on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122406/automatically-update-formula-field-after-generating-open-xml-word-document